# Why can't I see the camera, empty, lamp, speakers, and some physics in add object Menu when a python script is run

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a very long script for doing some specific action in the scene. When I run the script, mysteriously camera and other objects just disappear from the the Add menu in the working space. I am importing currently these libraries. Do I need to import more libraries in order to get full functioning Blender Interface.

```
import bpy
from bpy import *
import bmesh
import random
from random import randint
import bpy.props
from bpy.props import *
import os
import bpy.utils.previews
from bpy.types import Scene
```

and these two functions I used to register and unregister properties which i used for my task.

```
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.sub_divs = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="sub div", description='', default=9, min=9, max=50, update=update_func)
    bpy.types.Scene.seed = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="seed", default=0, update=update_func_seed)
    bpy.types.Scene.bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="color 1", default=False, update=toggle_bool)
    bpy.types.Scene.bool_invert = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="color 2", default=False, update=toggle_bool_invert)
    bpy.types.Scene.bool_color = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="color scheme", default=False, update=toggle_color)
    bpy.types.Scene.bool_toggle = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Toggle select", default=False, update=toggle_select)
    bpy.types.Scene.pieces = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Lipid types", min=0, max=10, default=0, update=update_pieces)
    global custom_icons
    custom_icons = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    script_path = bpy.context.space_data.text.filepath
    icons_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(script_path), "icons")
    custom_icons.load("custom_icons", os.path.join(icons_dir, "icon.png"), 'IMAGE')
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.sub_divs
    del bpy.types.Scene.seed
    del bpy.types.Scene.bool
    del bpy.types.Scene.bool_invert
    del bpy.types.Scene.pieces
    del bpy.types.Scene.p1
    del bpy.types.Scene.p2
    del bpy.types.Scene.p3
    del bpy.types.Scene.p4
    del bpy.types.Scene.p5
    del bpy.types.Scene.p6
    del bpy.types.Scene.p7
    del bpy.types.Scene.p8
    del bpy.types.Scene.p9
    del bpy.types.Scene.p10
    global custom_icons
    bpy.utils.preview.remove(custom_icons)
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Do I need to import more libraries for smooth work.

Comment: Could be an unforeseen consequence of using both `from bpy import *` and `bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)`.    Suggest not using `from bpy import *`

Comment: Is it possible the end of your script leaves you in Edit mode on a mesh?  If you are not in Object mode, you can only add mesh things while editing a mesh.

Comment: No. It is always in Object mode. I think, custom_icons = bpy.utils.previews.new() is the one which causes problem. Without this the script fails but do not hiding items from the Menus. So I have to look to replace this part with something else.